# Habilitar copy & paste en EditText de Android

Tags: android

Intento habilitar el copiado de contenido desde un EditText de Android en el clipboard pero funciona. Curiosamente con una presión prolongada sobre la pantalla aparece un (1) cursor y no dos cursores como debería y tampoco me aparecen las opciones de copiar y pegar (que en mi teléfono es un barra superior)

Uso AppCompat con API 16 y estoy probando en un teléfono Android 4.1.2 (JELLY_BEAN)

- He vuelto a hacer visible mi ActionBar por las dudas.
- He comprobado por la presencia del cursor al presionar que:

  - El longpress esta habilitado
  - El EditText es focusableInTouch
- El problema es independiente de si oculto o no el teclado virtual.

Quisiera evitar probar respuestas del tipo prueba esto y aquello ya que hay muchas combinaciones posibles a priori como:

```
        android:inputType= text / none
        android:textIsSelectable = true / false
        android:focusableInTouchMode = true / false
        android: enabled / disabled
        etc
```

Agradecido desde ya!

**EDIT**:

Aislar el error no era nada fácil así que cree un nuevo proyecto y comprobé que como menciona Piero en su respuesta-comentario hay algo que "bloquea" la funcionalidad y así era:

```
    AutoResizeEditText res_display = findViewById(R.id.resDisplay);
    res_display.setText("");
    res_display.setEnabled(true);
    res_display.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    res_display.setFocusable(true);
    res_display.setEnableSizeCache(false);
    res_display.setMovementMethod(null);
    // can be added after layout inflation; it doesn't have to be fixed
    // value
    res_display.setMaxHeight(330); // algún valor
```

Esas lineas representan un parche del autor de un EditText con texto auto-regulable en tamaño de la fuente:

https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/using-auto-resize-to-fit-edittext-in-android/

El problema es que ahora aparecen los dos cursores pero se desvanece rápidamente la barra con los botones [copy] y [paste] asi que el problema sigue irresuelto.

Comment: Copia el codigo del xml del editext y el del java para saber que esta haciendo el bloqueo del copy paste

Comment: A pedido de @Piero (que seguro aun no tiene los privilegios para comentar pero quiere ayudar) voy a pegar el código problematico. Gracias Piero!

Answer (score 2):

Como concepto general, para poder hacer uso del copy / paste con la interfaz nativa de Android es necesario:

Que el EditText sea "editable" (API level <11), selectable, focusable,...

Y finalmente pero no menos importante la ActionBar no puede estar oculta así que si tienes algo como:

```
    //to remove "information bar" above the action bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    //to remove the action bar (title bar)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Hay que quitarlo / comentarlo.

Con eso ya pude solucionar.

PD: se puede implementar un copy & paste personalizado que no dependa de la presencia del ActionBar utilizando ClipboardManager

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253786/how-to-copy-text-to-clip-board-in-android